# JqGrid inline editing with formatter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have this column model

```
{ name: 'CostShare', index: 'CostShare', width: 50, formatter: 'number', formatoptions: { decimalPlaces: 2, suffix: "%" }, resizeable: true, align: 'center', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editOptions: { number: true} }
```

which will produce a formatted value 1.00% from the source data of 1.  Problem is when I do inline editing it turns the formatted data into a textbox. It creates

```
<td aria-describedby="AdminCostTable_CostShare" title="1.00%" style="text-align: center;" role="gridcell"><input type="text" style="width: 98%;" id="1_CostShare" name="CostShare" role="textbox" class="editable"></td>
```

When you escape to close the editing "session" it probably tries to reformat again and turns the 1.00% into NaN.  Do I have to unformat the data manually or shouldn't the grid be doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to use the

```
         unformat: unformatPercent
```

hook in the colModel.  Seems like default format options should auto unformat themselves.  If it's just me doing something weird let me know. otherwise this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling editRow() manually in your code? If yes, try to call restoreRow() beforehand

Comment: I do call editrow and restoreRow.  I had to add an unformat function which was kinda janky.